# Lombok ошибка сборки при помощи Gradle в Docker

Tags: java, gradle, docker, lombok, jdk11

Сборка приложения на машине происходит успешно, а вот в Docker контейнере нет. Сразу напрашивается вопрос, чего-то нахватает, но чего?

*Проблема в том что Lombok не добавляет методы (@Builder, @AllArgsConstructor, ....)*

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
}
}

plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.10'
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

...

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
     compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.2'
    apt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gradle:4.10.2-jre11-slim

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle build

CMD ["gradle","run"]
```

Comment: Сразу напрашивается вопрос какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: @RomanC Ну так, это cannot found Symbol.

Comment: вам намекают на стектрейс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Всм? Какой может быть StackTrace, если Lombok не добавил методы?

Comment: ну значит лог сборки

Comment: Lombok - это кодогенератор. То есть в процессе компиляции на этапе обработки аннотацией будут созданы несколько class-файлов. Смогут эти созданные комплиятором файлы куда-то записаться? На сколько я понимаю, без подмонтированных каталогов, файловая система docker-образа работает в режиме только чтения.